# Which countries apply the EU rail passenger rights domestically?

Tags: uk, trains, legal, cancellations

I recently discovered that there are some general European rights, similar to those for air travel, that apply to rail journeys within Europe, detailed [here](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/rail/index_en.htm). For example, there is quite a powerful-sounding right which says:

> If you are told you will arrive at your final destination with a delay
>   of at least 1 hour, you are entitled to cancel your travel plans and
>   request an immediate refund of the cost of your ticket (sometimes in
>   full, sometimes only for the part of the journey not made.)

However, the page also says:

> European countries can decide whether or not these rights also apply
>   to domestic trains (urban, suburban, regional, etc.) and international
>   trains that start or finish their journey outside the EU.

So which countries apply these rights domestically? I'm particularly interested in the UK, but answers for other countries would no doubt be useful too.

Comment: The UK has even better rights than the EU minimums! [See Delay Repay on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Rail_Conditions_of_Carriage#Delay_Repay) for the minimum, and note that many companies trigger at 30 or 40 minutes

Comment: @Gagravarr: "If you arrive more than 60 minutes late at your destination station, due to the fault of the railway, you will be entitled to a minimum of 50% of the price paid for the relevant portion of the journey (Condition 42).". That sounds worse than what I quoted... or am I missing something?

Comment: For [Cross Country trains, as a random example](http://www.crosscountrytrains.co.uk/media/285021/delay_repay_form.pdf), 30-59 minutes late gets you 50% of the single ticket cost back, 60-119 gets you 100% of the single ticket cost back, and 120+ gets you the whole return cost back

Comment: Note that there exist **EU** rail passenger rights and (much older) **CIV** rail passenger rights.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's true that EU "laws" are not automatically valid, instead, specific countries need to implement them in their local laws.

I will focus on the lateness part here (not luggage and/or injuries).

Some common rules not always listed include:
a) No refund if some other train with less delay (than eg. 1h) was available
b) No refund if you were informed about the delay before bying the ticket
c) Special rules (or no refund at all) for discounted tickets like week/month/year pass etc.
d) How/where to get the refund varies greatly
e) Sometimes, refunds are coupons with expiration date
f) For two-way-tickets, the price of one way is used for the calculations

Some countries, in alphabetical order (might add more later):

**Austria**
More than 1h late, not only regional trains: 25% refund *if* these 25% are at least 4€
More than 2h late, not only regional trains: 50% refund *if* these 50% are at least 4€
http://www.oebb.at/en/Services/Passengers_rights/Train_cancellation__delay/index.jsp

**France**
Depending on the company eg. one of these:
a) 1h 25%, 2h 50%
b) 1h 25%, 2h 50%, 3h 75%
c) 30min 20%, 1h 50%, 2h 100%
Not all trains are eligible, domestic trains can be queried online.
http://faq.captaintrain.com/article/168-delayed-train-compensation

**Germany**
similar to Austria
http://www.bahn.com/i/view/GBR/en/services/passenger_rights/passengers-rights-online-form.shtml

**Italy**
For trains with mandatory seat reservation: 1h 25%, 2h 50%
Cancelling the journey and getting a full refund (for the part not used, if applicable) is possible too.
http://www.italia.it/en/useful-info/rights-for-tourists/railway-transportation.html

**Netherlands**
Depending on the company and the delay reason eg. one of these:
a) 1h 25%, 2h 50%
c) 30min 20%, 1h 50%, 2h 100%
https://www.nsinternational.nl/en/after-the-journey/compensation-for-delays

**Norway**
30min 50%, with some exceptions
https://www.nsb.no/en/our-tickets/booking-conditions/how-to-claim-a-refund-and-compensation

**Spain**
Varies depending on route, train and reason.

**Sweden**
1h 50%
https://www.sj.se/sj/jsp/polopoly.jsp?d=5684&a=175894&l=en

**Switzerland**
1h 25%, 2h 50%, only if the refund is at least 6CHF.
https://www.sbb.ch/en/station-services/services/sbb-customer-service/passenger-rights/helpfaqs.html

**UK**
1h late 50% refund, or 100% if journey cancelled
http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/times_fares/ticket_types/72098.aspx

About hotel costs etc. if necessary, on many sites it is not mentioned at all, so I would not rely on that. I've seen something for Austria and Switzerland, but somewhat limited.

Comment: Most UK train operators have more generous compensation agreements than quoted

Comment: Interesting, comprehensive list, thank you. Appears that the UK does not decide to apply these rules to domestic trains, at least not universally.